# Covariance matrix of beta coefficients for constrained multiple regression

Tags: regression, least-squares, covariance-matrix, constrained-regression, constrained-optimization

I have a linear least-squares problem with constraints that two of the coefficients must be non-negative. For a typical (unconstrained) least squares estimation, I know that the variance-covariance matrix of the coefficients is defined by:

$\hat {Var}(\hat \beta) = \hat \sigma^2 \cdot (X^TX)^{-1}$

Where $X$ is the design matrix, $\hat \beta$ is the vector of regression coefficients and $\hat \sigma^2$ is the residual variance.

How does this change for a constrained least squares problem?